# I am designing a grid-based outlier detection method in matlab.Is there a method to find number of points and store the grid points in each grid?

Tags: matlab, grid, distance, k-means, outliers

I am designing a grid-based outlier detection method using distance based approach and k means clustering in matlab.I have used "kmeans" function for clustering and "grid on" to show the grids. I want to know if there is way in matlab so that i can find number of points in each grid so that i can classify it as a "dense" cell or "sparse" cell.If the number of points in a grid is more than a threshold it can be said to be "dense".I need to find distance between each point in a sparse grid and centroid of each cluster to find which point is the outlier.If min(distances between a test object O in a sparse grid and cenroid of each cluster)>threshold value it is outlier.Can you suggest a method to implement this in matlab.

Comment: Is this 2d or 3d data?

Comment: i am using 2d grid design.i will verify the result using various UCI repository datasets.